# infopath query and sql injection problem

Tags: .net, sql, infopath

How can I protect my site from sql injection when Im getting ?details = value

from url

and the looking for the object in xml column in database with specified value ?

here is sample code:

```
sqlQuery = string.Format(@"
                    SELECT 
                        [data]

                    FROM " + schema + @".[MyOBjects] 
                    WHERE 

                        " data.exist('/data["theValue"=\"{0}\"]') = 1" + 



                    ", property, value);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this query running against SQL Server? If so you can use [`sql:variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) in your `exists` clause to reference parameters if that was the part you were asking about.

Comment: does it work in xquery ?

Comment: Yes, See this recent question for an example http://stackoverflow.com/q/7256649/73226

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following article about protecting your code from SQL injection: [Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

In your case you may want to look into using parameterized queries. Checkout "Step 3. Use Parameters with Dynamic SQL".

You could use something similar to this:

```
string connectionString = "...";
string schema = "...";
string value = "...";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT [data] FROM {0}.[MyOBjects] WHERE data.exist('/data[\"theValue\"=sql:variable(\"@value\")]') = 1", schema);

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255) { Value = value });

    ....
}
```

Comment: @gruber - Have updated my answer based on Martin Smith's suggestion to use the sql:variable() function.

Comment: @gruber - I'm not sure why it's not working in your case? I just tested it with an almost an identical query (table and column names different) and it ran and produced results for me. If you post your code I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure in the database, and instead of passing the values directly into the query pass them to the stored procedure.  If you really need the table name to be dynamic, there are methods out there for doing it.

Here's one for example: http://www.nigelrivett.net/SQLTsql/TableNameAsVariable.html